# How to send custom object with in String array

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have to pass a custom object to method, but the constraint is it accepts only String array, Is there any way to pass custom object to that method. Please note I cannot change the receiving method to accept the object.

Comment: Please provide a code example.  On the face of it what you are asking makes no sense!

Comment: You need to provide a context for this buddy! Regarding what your custom object is, what the method does, etc. Without that, the answers given below would not be of much help to you!

Comment: @VeeKay I want to pass a connection object and custom java bean  to that method, The method does some database operations by creating own connection, but we want to pass the connection object from caller. As i said above it accepts only String array, we cannot do any changes in he method params.

Comment: String only accepts a string.  You cannot circumvent that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Venkatesh, 
Why not simply create one more class that extents from the base, and override the method to accept the custom objects!
Hope the class you are using is not final.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with one `String` (or String[1]) using JSon.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming you have no back-channels available (such as a `Map<String, Object>` which both bits of code can get to) you'll probably need to serialize the object to text in some way. You could either do that through a naturally text-based serialization mechanism (e.g. JSON) or serialize it in a binary form and then convert it to text using base64. The code you call would then need to reverse the operation, of course.

Note that this won't serialize the object *reference* - so the code you call will end up with a separate object which happens to have the same data. If it makes any changes to the object, you *won't* see those changes in your calling code.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many ways that you can pass your object in a String format.

1. By overriding the `toString()` Method,
2. By creating a JSON object of your `Object`,
3. By creating a `Key/Value` map in XML format,

Like:

```
<Object>
    <properties>
        <property>
           <key>...</key>
           <value>...</value>
        </property>
    </properties>
</Object>
```

1. And You can make use of JAXB annotation that will translate your object in XML automatically.